# I want to send data as array in post request Laravel (Updated)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, api

This my controller:

```
public function addStdAnswer(Request $ans, Student_Answer $net)
{
    $validate = Validator::make($ans->all(), [
        'student_id' = 'required',
        'answer' = 'required',
        'module_id' = 'required',
    ]);
    
    if ($validate->fails()) {
        $messages = $validate->errors()->count()  1 ? 
                        $validate->errors()->all() : 
                        $validate->errors()->first();
        return response()->json([
            'code' = 400,
            'message' = $messages
        ], 400);
    } else { $document = new Student_Answer();
            $document = array(
                $document->student_id = $ans->student_id,
                $document->answer = $ans->answer,

                $document->module_id = $ans->module_id,
                $document->save(),
            );
        return response()->json([
            'code' = 201, 'message' = 'Answer Added Successfully',
            'object' = $document
        ], 201);
    }
}
```

I want to send module ids in an array and also want to store them in the database in different rows on behalf of the student id but I saw this error

[image]

Comment: Can you show your full error message ?

Comment: this is the full error msg

Error: Attempt to assign property &quot;module_id&quot; on string in file E:\Talimi Bagh\Talimi_Bagh\app\Http\Controllers\StudentAnswerController.php on line 39

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that you're overwriting the original **$document** value twice here:

```
$document = new Student_Answer();
$document = $ans->student_id;
$document = $ans->answer;
```

As a result, **$document** stores a string value of **$ans->answer**.

What you'll need here is something like (I don't know the property names of Student_Answer) this:

```
$document = new Student_Answer();
$document->student_id = $ans->student_id;
$document->answer = $ans->answer;
```

Comment: I want to send module_id as an array in the post request

Comment: I got that, but as i understand the error prevented you from doing so. The fix above should help with the error.

Comment: Regarding sending a post request, how are you doing it at the moment?

Comment: now i write this code also add your code in it

 $document = new Student_Answer();
            $document = array(
                $document->student_id = $ans->student_id,
                $document->answer = $ans->answer,

                $document->module_id = $ans->module_id,
                $document->save(),
            );

Comment: Please update the question with the latest code

Comment: question was updated plz check thank you

Comment: You're not doing what I posted in my answer.

Comment: i just add brackets after i tried your code sir

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. The above will fix the error you're getting but I can't help with anything else, sorry.